# Samba jobs disappear from Windows spooler

Tags: windows, linux, unix, printing, samba

I searched for similar issues to no avail, yet I have multiple systems exhibiting the same bizarre behavior.

Samba jobs printed to Windows printer shares arrive at the Windows workstation, but then disappear without printing.

This is most prevalent with Windows 7, but does also occur with Windows XP.

We have seen it mostly on HP2035 and HP CP2025 printers though has also occurred HP deskjets as well as Canon and Sharp multi use devices.

In a few case the most bizarre behavior is exhibited.

If you turn the printer off and back on before submitting a print job the job will print. If you send a subsequent job it will disappear. If you pause the printer, catch the job in the spooler, then cycle power on the printer, the job will disappear. You must cycle the printer power before the workstation sees the job.

On most of the affected systems, if jobs disappear from the Windows spooler then they always disappear regardless of power cycling or standing on your head or any other corrective/preventive action.

The version of Samba does not seem to be an issue.

I first saw this activity in a version 2.x on Unix. I have seen it continue through both Unix and Linux Samba versions 3.x. If a printer is exhibiting the behavior then it does not matter which Samba server sends a job, the behavior is the same.

It seems most prevalent on printers using Windows drivers, though the HP Universal driver exhibits the same behavior.

Any suggestions?